# DBCC TRACEON with the global flag

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

In the question [Need Help Troubleshooting Sql Server 2005 Deadlock Scenario](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/need-help-troubleshooting-sql-server-2005-deadlock-scenario) there was a suggestion of using `DBCC TRACEON (1204, -1)` to trace deadlocks globally.

When reading about this command in BOL [it states that it should only be used  while users or applications are not concurrently running statements on the system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187329.aspx). Does it mean that we must be in singleuser-mode when enabling this trace-flag? And in addition, why is it required and is it important to follow the advice? (Just seems a bit hard to follow in a production system that is always running.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This applies more to other trace flags (eg 610 for minimal logging) that affect the optimiser and important behaviours/optimisations

You should be OK with the deadlock trace flags 1204, 1205 and 1222