# Using (NOLOCK) in a READ COMMITTED transaction block

Tags: sql-server-2000, locking

We're using SQL Server 2000.

I'm wondering what the risks are if we use a `NOLOCK` hint within a `READ COMMITTED` transaction block, for example:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM clients (NOLOCK) WHERE clientID = 23249)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'TODO Update client'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'TODO Insert client'
    END

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

My concern is that the NOLOCK hint will allow a ditry read, despite the isolation level of the transaction block.

Is this possible?

PS: I know there is a debate to be had about why I am using a locking hint the in first place, but I would just like to know what the risks are in this scenario.

Comment: Looks like you are doing an `upsert`. Even at `readcommitted` your code has a race condition.

Comment: @Martin: I don't think I can do an `upsert` in SQL Server 2000. Can you explain the race condition though? I'm getting more and more worried :(

Comment: `UPSERT` is just the name of the pattern. 2008 has `MERGE` that helps here. [See this SO question for some answers that should work fine on 2000](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407857/only-inserting-a-row-if-its-not-already-there)

Comment: See this for ideas too: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/8351/630

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hint overrides the isolation level of the connection so you would indeed be allowing a dirty read from the clients table.

Comment: Eeek, was afraid of this.