# Insert if not exists, concurrently

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, concurrency

I am having concurrency issues with my inserts in a stored procedure.  The relevant part of the procedure is this:

```
select @_id = Id from table1 where othervalue = @_othervalue
IF( @_id IS NULL)
BEGIN
    insert into table1 (othervalue) values (@_othervalue)
    select @_id = Id from table1 where othervalue = @_othervalue
END
```

When we run 3 or 4 of these stored proc's concurrently we get multiple inserts on occasion.

I am planning on fixing this like so:

```
insert into table1 (othervalue) 
    select TOP(1) @_othervalue as othervalue from table1 WITH(UPDLOCK) 
    where NOT EXISTS ( select * from table1 where othervalue = @_othervalue )

select @_id = Id from table1 where othervalue = @_othervalue
```

The question is, is that how to concurrently insert without duplicates in sql server? The fact that i have to use TOP to only insert once disturbs me.

Comment: You don't have to use TOP. Remove the FROM table reference from the SELECT statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pros and Cons of Checking if value exist for unique column or let db raise unique error on inserting](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12551/pros-and-cons-of-checking-if-value-exist-for-unique-column-or-let-db-raise-uniqu)

Comment: @GSerg  I think you are correct.

Answer (score 8):

You could use a merge statement with `serializable` hint.

```
merge table1 with (serializable) as T 
using (select @_othervalue as othervalue) as S
on T.othervalue = S.othervalue
when not matched then
  insert (othervalue) values (othervalue);
```

Comment: Did you stress test your approach from two or more connections?

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov - I did it a while ago for another question on SO. I used two tabs in SSMS. First tested the `insert ... where not exist ...` pattern and found that you can get deadlocks and key violations so there it was necessary to use updlock and serializable. I then tested the merge statement and thought it would handle things a bit better and it did because there where no deadlocks but I still had to use serializable to not have key violations.

Comment: This is a really awesome answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want duplicates on the 'othervalue' column, you can do so by creating a `unique constraint` on that column. The query would be:

```
 ALTER TABLE table1
 ADD CONSTRAINT unique_c_othervalue UNIQUE(othervalue)
```

This would throw back an error if a query tried to insert a duplicate value into the 'othervalue' column.

Comment: How would that work if the unique constraint is a two row tuple?

Comment: @Chris How do you have a unique constraint that spans rows?

Comment: @Aaron I probably have my terminology off, but we have two rows that together need to be unique.  I don't think it is enforced in our schema.

Answer (score 3):

Use a unique constraint like @StanleyJohns recommends. Then use BEGIN TRY END TRY around your insert statement.

```
select @_id = Id from table1 where othervalue = @_othervalue
IF( @_id IS NULL)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        insert into table1 (othervalue) values (@_othervalue)
        select @_id = Id from table1 where othervalue = @_othervalue        
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        select @_id = Id from table1 where othervalue = @_othervalue        
    END CATCH
END
```